# Flutter Adjust bottom tab spacing for floating action button

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to adjust the spacing of my tabs so that it doesn't look awkward near the floating action button that I have docked at the bottom center. I was thinking of adding an 'invisible' icon but then that would mean the user might tap that by mistake and I don't think that's the best way around it.

**My Widget:**

```
Widget build(context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: TabBarView(
      children: _displayTabPages(),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      child: _createTabBar(),
      color: Colors.blue,
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      notchMargin: 5.0,
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      tooltip: 'Add Transaction',
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange[300],
      foregroundColor: Colors.black87,
      child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
      elevation: 2.0,
    ),
  );
}
```

**My TabBar:**

```
Widget _createTabBar() {
  return TabBar(
    tabs: [
      Tab(
        icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.list),
      ),
      Tab(
        icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt),
      ),
      Tab(
        icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chartPie),
      ),
      Tab(
        icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cog),
      )
    ],
    labelColor: Colors.white,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black87,
    indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
  );
}
```

The above creates this:

[image: bottom app bar]

Is there a way to fix the spacing in between the middle icons?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer two links below for your problem by adding centerItemText. Also you can use empty space instead of text.

https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-bottomappbar-navigation-with-fab-8b962bb55013

https://github.com/bizz84/bottom_bar_fab_flutter/blob/master/lib/fab_bottom_app_bar.dart